# ASP.NET application stopping event?

Tags: asp.net, events

I have a ASP.NET application which implements a custom in-memory cache. I'm using this as opposed to ASP.NET's caching mechanism as I needed a more complex way to handle what to drop from the cache. Part of this custom cache is a separate thread which occasionally searches for data to drop from the cache whenever it gets too large.

What I need to do is signal this cache maintenance thread to stop whenever the ASP.NET application 'exits'. I guess this basically amounts to when the web site is stopped in IIS.

Is there a pre-existing event I can utilise to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a Global.asax file and override the Application_End method.

http://www.csharphelp.com/2006/06/setting-up-global-objects-with-the-global-asax-file/

Comment: I think I read that this is sometimes called whenever the application goes idle - i.e. when it hasn't been used in X minutes. Is this the case? It's not necessarily a deal breaker, but it'd be good to know.

Thanks for your reply.

Comment: That's probably IIS killing off the application pool - they're generally set to be restarted after X number of requests or after Y number of minutes, whichever comes sooner, so you'd need to be mindful of that setting on your server.

Answer (score 1):

From the moment that you have this custom, memory cache, I suppose that your asp.net application communicate with this cache in many ways.

So why not make an a global value on this cashe, and make somthing like that on global.asax

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
  GlobalCacheUsed ++;
}

void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
  GlobalCacheUsed --;
}
```

and your thread just check for that **GlobalCacheUsed** value

Can I please ask you witch way you use to communicate with your apps ? I have make something similar with you, having class that I use both a database table and other cache that use a memory. My trigger to clear the cache is with user events, or with timers.

Hope this help you.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not sure what you mean by 'which way you use to communicate with your app'. Try to elaborate a little, and I'll help if I can. :)

Comment: How you have declare your data, and what is the way that the thread get them, and they are seperate from the pages ? Using static variable ?, using database ?, using something else ?